# Running Actinia on docker container

Tags: docker, git-bash, grass

I have recently heard about Actinia and I would like to try it out (I am remote sensing anaylst, I am not used to use command line )

I use Windows 10 . I have cloned Actinia on github and trying to use it on my docker container. I changed my windows containers to linux containers. Once I type in on my GitBash

```
docker-compose build --pull
```

It stops at step 16/49, while trying to connect to GRASS GIS. It iterates on the same problem,

```
GRASS GIS libgis version and date number not available
ERROR: Cannot open URL:
```

and the url he is trying to connect to.

Thus, I wonder if there is a configuration I am missing.

Source: https://github.com/mundialis/actinia_core/tree/master/docker

Comment: Hi, the "GRASS GIS libgis version and date number not available" is harmless (a fix is on the way, will be shipped with GRASS GIS 7.8.3), but the question is: on which URL does it get stuck? Do you have a proxy server in between your machine and the internet?

Comment: It throws a warning  from Step 13/49 : WARNING: GRASS GIS libgis version and date number not available
Then, in Step 16/49 :  RUN while IFS=, read -r ADDON SERVER; do unset URL; test -z $SERVER || URL="url=$SERVER"; grass --tmp-location EPSG:4326 --exec g.extension -s extension=$ADDON $URL;done < /src/grass_addons_list.csv

Comment: And my computer is not using a Proxy server,

Comment: The "WARNING: GRASS GIS libgis version and date number not available" you can ignore, as written in the message above. I don't know where it contacts the GitHub server in line https://github.com/mundialis/actinia_core/blob/master/docker/actinia-core/Dockerfile#L70 - can you reach GitHub? Here it works fine: https://hub.docker.com/repository/registry-1.docker.io/mundialis/actinia-core/builds/0c0b092c-bd14-4f12-a8f2-ab6db9c3e401

Comment: I dont have any problem with GitHub. I can see on your link  https://github.com/mundialis/actinia_core/blob/master/docker/actinia-core/Dockerfile#L70 that a Dockerfile is used. I haven't done that before, then , I will use this instructions. I will back when this is done, thank you!